# Why doesnt datastream print a transformation?

Tags: java, apache-flink

```
List<Integer> lst = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
DataStream<Integer> dataStream = env.fromCollection(lst);

dataStream.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<Integer, Integer>() {

    @Override
    public void flatMap(Integer integer, Collector<Integer> collector) throws Exception {
        collector.collect(new Integer(integer.intValue() + 1));
    }
});

dataStream.print();
env.execute("Executing list");
```

This ends up printing:

```
10> 4
9> 3
8> 2
12> 6
11> 5
4> 10
1> 7
2> 8
3> 9
7> 1
```

I'm assuming I am making a mistake somewhere in the `FlatMap` function or somewhere in the printing perhaps. I was trying to map it so that each element because incremented by 1.

Answer (score 0):

`dataStream.flatMap(...)` returns a transformed stream, but does not modify the original `dataStream`. You need to either rewrite this as

```
dataStream.flatMap(...).print();
```

or as

```
DataStream<Integer> transformed = dataStream.flatMap(...);
transformed.print();
```

Answer (score 0):

dataStream.flatMap(...).print()

not

dataStream.flatMap(...)
dataStream.print()